# Node.js My Request is Not Blocking

Tags: node.js, request, blocking

I'm new to node.js, and I'm trying to call a service, parse its data and return it as part of a view. I can't seem to get the request to block until the response is complete. The console always logs 'wrong' before 'right' (returning the 1,2,3 array). What am I missing?

app.js

```
  var reading = require('./reading'); 

  app.get('/reading', function(req, res){
  res.render('reading/index.stache', 
    {
      locals : { ids : reading.list},
      partials : {
             list : '{{#ids}}{{.}}<br />{{/ids}}'
      }
  });
});
```

reading.js

```
var request,
    http = require('http'),
    host = 'google.com',
    path ='/';

var list = function(){

var connection = http.createClient(80, host),
    request = connection.request(path);

request.addListener('response', function(response){
    var data = '';
    response.addListener('data', function(chunk){ 
        data += chunk; 
    });
    response.addListener('end', function(){
        console.log('right')
        //var results = JSON.parse(data); 
        // i need results from json
        return [88234,883425,234588];
    });
});

request.end();
console.log('wrong');
return [1,2,3];
}

module.exports.list = list;
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but I just want to point out that you are requiring the 'request' module, but then using Node's core 'createClient' instead.

Comment: sorry, that was left over from other attempts....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can't get the request to block until the response is back.

That's because there is communication latency between sending the request of and getting the response back. It would be stupid to wait and do nothing whilst that latency is happening.

Use callbacks and asynchronous control flow.

```
var list = function(callback){

var connection = http.createClient(80, host),
    request = connection.request(path);

request.addListener('response', function(response){
    var data = '';
    response.addListener('data', function(chunk){ 
        data += chunk; 
    });
    response.addListener('end', function(){
        console.log('right')
        // USE A CALLBACK >:(
        callback([88234,883425,234588]);
    });
});

request.end();
}
```

Comment: You are implicitly converting the buffer to a string by using `+=`. If you are going to append like that, then you need to do `response.setEncoding('utf8'), otherwise you could break multi-byte characters in the response.

Comment: how do i use this in context of my app.js? would res.render(...) be the callback function?

Comment: @bluevoodoo1 res.render would be in the callback

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to run anything in sync have a look at the [sync module](https://github.com/0ctave/node-sync). It's based on fibers.